How to perform in-place update of CredentialsParameter in jenkins pipeline groovy
Here's a simple stage wherein I'm looping through all jobs and checking if they have a CredentialParameterDefinition
If yes, looping again within each job against all CredentialParameters and trying to swap existing credential with some other value within each of the credential parameter
The job might have other Parameters like String, Hidden Parameters etc
stage("Process Pipeline Jobs") {
    Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job).each { job ->
        def jobFullName = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(job.fullName).getName()
        if (jobFullName.toString().contains("test-swap-creds")) {
            if (job?.isBuildable()) {
                def paramsDef = job.getProperty(ParametersDefinitionProperty)
                if ((paramsDef != null && paramsDef != "") &&
                        paramsDef.getParameterDefinitions().toString().contains("CredentialsParameterDefinition")) {
                    for (param in paramsDef.getParameterDefinitions()) {
                        int i = 0
                        if (param.getDefaultParameterValue().getClass().getName().toString().contains("CredentialsParameterValue")) {
                            i++
                            def defaultParam = param.getDefaultParameterValue()
                            def cls = defaultParam.getClass().getName()
                            def credId = defaultParam.getValue()
                            def paramName = defaultParam.getName()
                            
                            //Want to swap credId and ParaName with  
                            def paramNameSwap = "swap_param" + i
                            def credIdSwapVal = "swap_value" + i

                            job.addProperty(new ParametersDefinitionProperty(
                                    new com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsParameterDefinition(paramNameSwap, "Description", credIdSwapVal, "com.datapipe.jenkins.vault.credentials.common.VaultSSHUserPrivateKeyImpl", false)
                            ))
                            // It is deleting all credential parameters and creating only one
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

No matter how many Parameters are there in job, regardless of type, all are getting deleted and only one credential parameter remains
Searched javadocs for updateProperty for job
Could not find same
Would want all parameters to stay intact and only credentials parameters need to be updated in-place with new values
Some logic might sound weird related to job.addProperty at the at place and incrementing var i, it's just so to make query to be put cross in simple manner
